# Python Class vs File level variables

Tags: design, python, scope

I have the following class:

```
import Radar

class Domain(Radar):
    URL = 'https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx'
    ADDRESS_KEYS = ('mailing_address', 'city_name', 'state_name', 'zip_code',
                    'country_name')
    GENERAL_PARAMS = {'format': 'json'}
    BALANCE_PARAMS = {**Radar.GENERAL_PARAMS, 'account': 'balance'}
    SUCCESSFUL_QUERY = 1
    API_KEY_ERROR_REASON = 'Invalid API Key'
    MASKED_ENTITY_INDICATOR = 'To View Unmasked Data'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.entity_title = 'Crawling'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The class' methods (only them) access each of these constant static members few times.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of putting these variables in the outer scope (as a file level variables - and not class level static variables)?

Even though I know both approaches would work, I wonder where is the best place put the variables - inside the class or above it.

The other option:

```
import Radar

URL = 'https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx'
ADDRESS_KEYS = ('mailing_address', 'city_name', 'state_name', 'zip_code',
                'country_name')
GENERAL_PARAMS = {'format': 'json'}
BALANCE_PARAMS = {**Radar.GENERAL_PARAMS, 'account': 'balance'}
SUCCESSFUL_QUERY = 1
API_KEY_ERROR_REASON = 'Invalid API Key'
MASKED_ENTITY_INDICATOR = 'To View Unmasked Data'

class Domain(Radar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.entity_title = 'Crawling'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mostly stylistic choice. In the end, it doesn't matter. There are some finer differences depending on how they are used.

- If the constants are only used within the module, using module-level variables is more convenient. (Compare class variables below).
- If the constants are used outside of this module, then module-level variables have the advantage that you can `import` them.
- Class variables have the advantage that they are bundled in that class. This may provide a more convenient interface because you don't have to pass them around individually. For example, the [`Enum` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html?highlight=enum) does this nicely. But in reverse: why would you be bundling them unless they are used together?

Class variables in Python do have some gotchas.

- Python doesn't have true constants, so anyone could reassign them. (To create read-only fields in Python, you must use a `property`, or more generally: the descriptor protocol).
- These variables can be shadowed by subclasses, or by instance variables.
- The variables can only be accessed through the class or its instances. E.g. to access the `URL` variable in a method, you have to say `Domain.URL` or `self.URL`. Module-level variables can be accessed directly.

In general, Python doesn't force you to stuff everything into a class. You should use this freedom because most variables or functions *don't* belong into a class. If in doubt, use free variables/functions instead of fields/methods within a class. You can always change your mind later and refactor.